# curl_multi_perform.How can I use curl_multi_perform no-block when call back function for upload audio stream

Tags: c++, c, curl

I used curl_multi_perform to upload audio stream ,and there are easy handles added into multi include upload audio stream .
But  when curl_multi_perform executed, call back for upload audio stream, the curl_multi_perform is blocked, so the other easy handle can not exec immediately。 How can I call back for update audio stream ,curl_multi_perform not block?
There is another issue, When I call back for update audio stream ,the call back function want a size data, the size is to large, then  the call back block too long . How can I modify the size for call back?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to implement callbacks so that they do what they are supposed to as quickly as possible and then return back.

The callback for uploads should read data into the curl''s buffer and return, which on a modern CPU and setup could be done in microseconds. That's not going to alter the "non-blocking" nature of the API and is virtually invisible to other transfers going on in parallel.

> the call back function want a size data, the size is to large, then the call back block too long

Then you're doing it wrong. The callback says how much you *can* deliver to it at the most, you don't have to fill up the entire buffer. If reading data takes a long time, then you should return less data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply。But,I find curl_multi_perform cannot return until the call back return,the callback must read audio stream from mic, so it must wait data until data ready。 And, for the second question, I tried to return less data,but the call back immediately called again for the left data that not be returned the last time, so curl_multi_perform do not call other until all except data been give.